# Не правильное расстояние компоновки

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qlayout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде получается сделать компоновку, но вот есть некоторая проблема с левым меню. Когда я делаю во весь экран

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

происходит не понятное расширение и отдаление виджетов...

Как можно это исправить так, чтобы центральная часть отодвигалась пропорционально с левым меню и убрать этот обрыв между виджетами.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1253</width>
    <height>801</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <property name="animated">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_6">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_7">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>17</number>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>3</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>24</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>31</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>751</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>161</width>
          <height>751</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);
border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border-radius: 20px;

</string>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="menu">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>31</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>31</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/menu/Изображения/3030.png);
border: 1px solid #a112fe;
border-radius: 10;
</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>6</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);
border: 2px solid rgba(34, 31, 46, 0); ;

border-radius: 10</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="pixmap">
              <pixmap>../apexx/Nikita_Pfeyfer2.png</pixmap>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="weapon">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Copperplate Gothic Bold</family>
               <pointsize>14</pointsize>
               <weight>50</weight>
               <bold>false</bold>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    ;
    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);      
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    padding: 5px;
    }

QPushButton:hover {
   
    
    
    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
    }

QPushButton:pressed {
    border-style: inset;
   
    
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    }</string>
             </property>
             <property name="inputMethodHints">
              <set>Qt::ImhNone</set>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Weapons</string>
             </property>
             <property name="autoExclusive">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="pixmap">
              <pixmap>../apexx/Nikita_Pfeyfer4.png</pixmap>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="spravka">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Copperplate Gothic Bold</family>
               <pointsize>12</pointsize>
               <weight>50</weight>
               <bold>false</bold>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    ;
    
    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    padding: 5px;

    }
QPushButton:hover {
   
    
    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
    }

QPushButton:pressed {
    border-style: inset;
   
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    }</string>
             </property>
             <property name="inputMethodHints">
              <set>Qt::ImhNone</set>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Reference</string>
             </property>
             <property name="autoExclusive">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
        <property name="spacing">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="bottomMargin">
         <number>191</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>62</number>
          </property>
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <family>Copperplate Gothic Bold</family>
              <pointsize>28</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">color: rgb(253, 253, 253);</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Main Menu</string>
            </property>
            <property name="alignment">
             <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>40</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>18</number>
            </property>
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>114</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
              <property name="spacing">
               <number>5</number>
              </property>
              <item>
               <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_3">
                <property name="styleSheet">
                 <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);
border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;
border-radius: 10</string>
                </property>
                <property name="frameShape">
                 <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="frameShadow">
                 <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
                </property>
                <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
                 <property name="spacing">
                  <number>6</number>
                 </property>
                 <item>
                  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
                   <item>
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
                     <property name="font">
                      <font>
                       <family>Bahnschrift SemiBold</family>
                       <pointsize>22</pointsize>
                       <weight>75</weight>
                       <bold>true</bold>
                      </font>
                     </property>
                     <property name="styleSheet">
                      <string notr="true">color: rgb(194, 194, 194);</string>
                     </property>
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>Версия</string>
                     </property>
                     <property name="alignment">
                      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item>
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
                     <property name="font">
                      <font>
                       <family>Bahnschrift SemiBold</family>
                       <pointsize>22</pointsize>
                       <weight>75</weight>
                       <bold>true</bold>
                      </font>
                     </property>
                     <property name="styleSheet">
                      <string notr="true"/>
                     </property>
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>1.0 BETA</string>
                     </property>
                     <property name="alignment">
                      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                  </layout>
                 </item>
                </layout>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
                <property name="orientation">
                 <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                 <size>
                  <width>20</width>
                  <height>40</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
               </spacer>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textBrowser_2">
                <property name="styleSheet">
                 <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);
border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;
border-radius: 10</string>
                </property>
                <property name="html">
                 <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;Информация&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;Программа находится в разработке, поэтому, пока что присудствует не вся информация &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>29</width>
                <height>17</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
            <item>
             <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
              <property name="spacing">
               <number>15</number>
              </property>
              <item>
               <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textBrowser">
                <property name="styleSheet">
                 <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);
border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;
border-radius: 10</string>
                </property>
                <property name="html">
                 <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;ApexHelper&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;Эта программа предназначена для того, чтобы помочь новичкам или опытным игрокам более лучше освоить игру&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;_Apex Legends_&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;Тут ты найдёшь подробное описание каждого оружия,&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;обвеса и прочих вещей.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;С уважением, Разработчик &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;ApexHelper&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
                <property name="orientation">
                 <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                 <size>
                  <width>40</width>
                  <height>20</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
               </spacer>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textBrowser_3">
                <property name="styleSheet">
                 <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);
border: 2px solid #6c6c00;
border-radius: 10</string>
                </property>
                <property name="html">
                 <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:16pt; color:#c2c2c2;&quot;&gt;Кому принадлежит&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:16pt;&quot;&gt;Все данные, изображения и прочее из программы, принадлежат компании&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:16pt;&quot;&gt; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#6f6f0a;&quot;&gt;Respawn Entertainment&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:14pt;&quot;&gt;Никому более.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:14pt;&quot;&gt;Их материал был повзаимствован для помощи игрокам.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
   <zorder>label</zorder>
   <zorder>frame</zorder>
   <zorder>frame_3</zorder>
   <zorder>textBrowser</zorder>
   <zorder>frame_4</zorder>
   <zorder>textBrowser_3</zorder>
   <zorder></zorder>
  </widget>
  <action name="action">
   <property name="text">
    <string>справка</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="../apexx/our/ApexFone.qrc"/>
  <include location="../apexx/our/menu.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Все подклассы `QWidget` могут использовать `layout` для управления
своими дочерними элементами.
Функция `QWidget::setLayout()` применяет `layout` к виджету.

Система компоновки *Qt* предоставляет простой и мощный способ автоматической
организации дочерних виджетов внутри виджета, чтобы гарантировать,
что они эффективно используют доступное пространство.
... читаем дальше.

У вас есть центральный виджет, полезно почитать -
[**Qt Main Window Framework**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework)

```
self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
```

мы выбрали `QHBoxLayout` для расположения дочерних виджетов,
потому что хотим разместить в него два виджета. 
Условно левый `left_frame` и правый `right_frame`,
у вас это `frame` и `verticalLayout_4`, т.е. для правой стороны вы не
создаете виджет, а лучше это делать, т.е. создавать.

Давайте правильные имена переменным/объектам.
Глядя на `frame` - что вы можете сказать, что это? ,
а если вы посмотрите на `left_frame`, то понятно сразу, что это левый фрейм.

И еще:

- не надо предоставлять невоспроизводимые примеры.
  Вы используете файл ресурсов для изображений.
  Вам  надеюсь уже понятна эта тема, поэтому примените ее когда все вопросы уже решены.
- желательно также опубликовать свои изображения, которые вы используете.
- не пытайтесь сразу нарисовать все что вы хотите увидеть в окне,
  а потом разбираться что не так, делайте пошагово - добавили виджет,
  добавили макет и посмотрели все ли так.
  Добавили следующий виджет и макет - опять посмотрели все ли вас устраивает.
  Потом начинаете создавать виджеты, которые вы собираетесь разместить в первый виджет
  и добавляете эти созданные виджеты в соответствующий макет первого виджета.
  Смотрели все ли так. И.т.д.

В общем я преобразовал ваш **`.ui`** в **`.py`** и внес некоторые изменения на свой розум.
Вы легко увидите что я поменял и где, а также подумайте почему я это сделал.

Чтобы хорошо научится использовать менеджеры компоновки - нужна практика.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
#        MainWindow.resize(1253, 801)
        MainWindow.resize(900, 601)

        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
# ???        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
# ???        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) #+ centralwidget
#        self.horizontalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(3, 0, 24, 31)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
#        self.horizontalLayout_7.setSpacing(17)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        
#        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.left_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget) 
        
#        self.left_frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 751)) 
#        self.left_frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 751))
        self.left_frame.setMinimumWidth(80)

        self.left_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(146, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"border-radius: 20px;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.left_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.left_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.left_frame.setObjectName("left_frame")
       
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.left_frame) # self.left_frame
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QPushButton()             # - self.frame
#        self.menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(31, 31))
#        self.menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(151, 151))

        self.menu.setMinimumHeight(50)                                     # +++
        
#        self.menu.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/menu/Изображения/3030.png);\n"
#                                vvvvvvvvvvvv               vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.menu.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(boy.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;\n"
"border: 1px solid #a112fe;\n"
"border-radius: 25;\n"
"")
        self.menu.setText("")
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.menu)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.left_frame)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);\n"
"border: 2px solid rgba(34, 31, 46, 0); ;\n"
"\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.label_9.setText("")
        
#        self.label_9.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../apexx/Nikita_Pfeyfer2.png"))
# +++                                                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.label_9.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(50, 50))         # +++
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        
        self.label_9.setMinimumWidth(50)                                       # +++
        
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_9, 0)
        
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.left_frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    color: rgb(78, 175, 94);      \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.weapon, 1)
        
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem)

        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.left_frame)
        
               
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(146, 31, 46);")
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("head3.png").scaled(45, 45))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        
        self.label_10.setMinimumWidth(55)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_10, 0)
        self.spravka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.left_frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.spravka.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.spravka.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.spravka.setFont(font)
        self.spravka.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(78, 175, 94);\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"\n"
"    }\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.spravka.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.spravka.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.spravka.setObjectName("spravka")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.spravka, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.left_frame, stretch=1)     # + stretch
        
# ???        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
# ???        self.horizontalLayout_7.addItem(spacerItem1)

# ==============================================================================
#right_frame

        self.right_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)        
        self.right_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(146, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"border-radius: 20px;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.right_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.right_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.right_frame.setObjectName("right_frame")
        
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.right_frame)

#        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, 0, 191)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)

        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")

# ???        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
# ???        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, -1, 0)
# ???        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(62)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(5)                                 # +++

        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(253, 253, 253); background-color: #105652;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
        
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem2)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
#        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(114, -1, -1, -1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(18)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(5)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        
        # версия
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(194, 194, 194);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textBrowser_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(29, 17, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(15)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem5)
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #6c6c00;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textBrowser_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
# ++ vvv две строки
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem2)
        
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        
#        self.horizontalLayout_7.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.right_frame, stretch=4)   # + stretch

#        self.horizontalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        
        self.label.raise_()
        self.left_frame.raise_()
        self.frame_3.raise_()
        self.textBrowser.raise_()
        self.textBrowser_3.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
        self.spravka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reference"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Версия"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1.0 BETA"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">Информация</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Программа находится в разработке, поэтому, пока что присудствует не вся информация </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Эта программа предназначена для того, чтобы помочь новичкам или опытным игрокам более лучше освоить игру</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">_Apex Legends_</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Тут ты найдёшь подробное описание каждого оружия,</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;\"> </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">обвеса и прочих вещей.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">С уважением, Разработчик </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">Кому принадлежит</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Все данные, изображения и прочее из программы, принадлежат компании</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\"> </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#6f6f0a;\">Respawn Entertainment</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Никому более.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Их материал был повзаимствован для помощи игрокам.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "справка"))
        
# ??? import ApexFone_rc
# ??? import menu_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где преобразованный ui файл? и я ещё заметил, что у вас первый столбец с информацией сильно отдаляется от 2 и 3

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер я преобразовал `ваш .ui` в .py и в .py внес изменения. которые вам предоставил и прокомментировал. То что что-то от чего-то сильно отдаляется - это не проблема, т.к. все регулируется.

Comment: Я всё же не могу понять, некоторых ваших слов. Нам всё равно придётся накладывать компановку на centralwidget и как раз из-за этого полетит размер изображений и некоторая компановка. Но всё же, не могли бы вы мне конкретно указать, с чего начинать учить qtdesigner, а то у меня путаница в голове и кажется, что я программирую в слепую... И не могли бы вы сказать, вы случаем в дискорде есть? У меня есть один вопрос

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер я же вам предоставил ссылки, которые надо прочитать и написал что надо много практиковаться. По Qt Designer много чего написано, читайте все подряд и через какое-то время прояснение наступит. https://realpython.com/qt-designer-python/ На вопросы я отвечаю только на этом сайте.

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnXoOwWWR1I&ab_channel=ChairmanStudios - это вам бонусом. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер  + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPgwQJUFPIw&ab_channel=SpinnTV

Comment: Спасибо за эти классные ролики!!!